# File upload giving me file count less than zero in master pages

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Hi every one i am trying to upload file s in my master page. I have so many forms in master pages . In one of the page i want to use a file upload control.

see my master page design:

```
<body> 

     <form id="form1" runat="server" action="Upload.ashx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <div>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cntBody"  runat="server">
               //This is the Body where i am putting other pages..

                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>



     </form>

</body>
```

After seeing so many examples , tutorials about file upload control i concluded 2 important things in file upload control are:

- enctype='multipart/form-data'
- input file id.

Where to put the enctype while in case of master pages? I used like above but it is giving me file count less than zero ashx handler.
 Every time saying xml parse error no element found!!

```
 <td>
               <input type="file" name="files[]" id="image" />

</td>

     ......

       var fileUpload = $("#image").get(0);
            var files = fileUpload.files;

            var data = new FormData();
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
            }

                ajax.Post("../Scripts/uploadify/UploadHandler.ashx", JSON.stringify({ objEnt: args }),false).success(function () {

        }
```

I want to send some data to my ashx, and as well as image!!
Please help me some body.

Answer (score 0):

> Where to put the enctype while in case of master pages?

Assuming this is your actual question...I feel your pain. That's the way ASP.NET WebForms work, you can add ONLY ONE form to your aspx page, which goes against HTML Standards and brings issues like the one you are describing.
You can still change attributes of your form from your child page by getting a reference to the master page (note, that the page class exposes a property that reference the master page class) and then find the form. See example below...

```
 var form = Page.Master.FindControl("form1") as HtmlForm;

if (form != null)
    form.Enctype = "multipart/form-data";
```

Hope it makes sense

Comment: If i do this in page load will it make effect ashx hanlder???Still I m getting file count zero every time!!!

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase your question if it has nothing to do with referencing the master page